# Upload an image as part of a form with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image

I need some guidance on uploading an image as part of a form with several text fields with AngularJS. I've already looked at several posts and articles on the web and stackoverflow and most of them upload images on their own or do not include Json data as well. So here is my specific situation:

- I have several fields in the same form and would like to create the new item as the user clicks "add item"
- I need to upload the file to a local directory "/images" and send the URL path+file name to an API with the rest of the data created in the form.

Example:

- drop file entry6.jpg in /images directory
- my code creates the following object sent to API:

  ```
  {
  "title": "Big sale",
  "link": "http://www.example.com",
  "image": images/entry6.jpg
  "id": 1
  }
  ```

Can you help me?

Current HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="EditClients" class="container">
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newClientsItem.title" required="required" class="form-control"/><br/>
    <label>Link</label>
    <input type="url" ng-model="newClientsItem.link" required="required" class="form-control"/><br/>
    <label>Image</label><br/>
    <input type="file" ng-model="newClientsItem.image"/>
   <a ng-click="createClientsItem(newClientsItem)" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Add</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

And JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngResource', 'ngTagsInput']);

//constants for APIs
app.constant("clientsUrl", "http://www.example.com:3001/api/clients/");

app.controller('EditClients', function($scope, $http, $resource, clientsUrl) {

    $scope.clientsItemsResource = $resource(clientsUrl + ":id", {id: "@id"},
            { create : { method: "POST"}, save: { method: "PUT"}}
        );

    $scope.listClientsItems = function() {
        $scope.clientsItems = $scope.clientsItemsResource.query();
    };

    $scope.deleteClientsItem = function(clientsItem) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you to delete this item?')) {
            clientsItem.$delete().then(function () {
                $scope.clientsItems.splice($scope.clientsItems.indexOf(clientsItem), 1);
            });
        }
    };

    $scope.createClientsItem = function (clientsItem) {

        //creates the new item
  new $scope.clientsItemsResource(clientsItem).$create().then(function (newClientsItem) {
      $scope.clientsItems.push(newClientsItem);
    });
};

    $scope.updateClientsItem = function(clientsItem) {
        clientsItem.$save();
        toastr.success('Item sauvé');
    };

    $scope.listClientsItems();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use formidable(https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) to handle uploading files in angular.js and nodejs.

Comment: How would you integrate it into a full form that sends an object at the end?